# Fix broken apt: insserv: Service killprocs has to be enabled to start service single

Tags: debian, apt, arm

After I made a system upgrade (`apt-get upgrade`) on a Debian box, I get an error every time I try to use `apt-get`. Example:

```
# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-41+deb7u1) ...
insserv: Service killprocs has to be enabled to start service single
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initscripts
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried to find a solution, but can't find anything that looks like this. First of all I have this packet which is "not fully installed or removed". But I can't find the command to locate it.

But it lists about 20 packets, so there must be a better way to find this packet.

To fix the packet system I have tried normal procedures, like:

```
apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove 
apt-get -f install
dpkg --configure -a
```

The clean command is good, but the install command will fail with as shown above.

In a desperate try, I tried to reinstall insserv (not sure it's the packet which is broken), but it fails the same way:

```
# apt-get install --reinstall insserv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 63.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main insserv armel 1.14.0-5 [63.8 kB]
Fetched 63.8 kB in 0s (85.5 kB/s)
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-41+deb7u1) ...
insserv: Service killprocs has to be enabled to start service single
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initscripts
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Hope some of you can help me fix the issue.

**Edit**
Got a bit further:

```
dpkg --audit
The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 initscripts          scripts for initializing and shutting down the system

The following packages are missing the list control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
 insserv              boot sequence organizer using LSB init.d script dependenc
 ssmtp                extremely simple MTA to get mail off the system to a mail

The following packages are missing the md5sums control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
 insserv              boot sequence organizer using LSB init.d script dependenc
 ssmtp                extremely simple MTA to get mail off the system to a mail
 binutils             GNU assembler, linker and binary utilities
```

But I'm still not able to fix anything:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure initscripts
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: initscripts is broken or not fully installed
```

and:

```
# apt-get install --reinstall initscripts
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for initscripts:armel
```

Comment: Duplicate here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97233/4671  Please don't crosspost. One of these should be closed. Can they be merged?