# Fixing a broken packet system (apt-get)

Tags: linux, apt

After I made a system upgrade (apt-get upgrade) on a debian box, I get an error everytime i tries to use apt-get. Example:

```
# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-41+deb7u1) ...
insserv: Service killprocs has to be enabled to start service single
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initscripts
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried to find a solution, but can't find anything that looks like this. First of all I have this packet which is "not fully installed or removed". But I can't find the command to locate it. Have tried:

```
dpkg -l | grep rc
```

But it list about 20 packets, so there must be a better way to find this packet.

To fix the packet system I have tried normal procedures, like:

```
apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove 
apt-get -f install
dpkg --configure -a
```

The clean command is good, but the install command will fail with as shown above.

In a desperate try, I tried to reinstall insserv (not sure it's the packet which is broken), but it fails the same way:

```
# apt-get install --reinstall insserv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 63.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main insserv armel 1.14.0-5 [63.8 kB]
Fetched 63.8 kB in 0s (85.5 kB/s)
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-41+deb7u1) ...
insserv: Service killprocs has to be enabled to start service single
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initscripts
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `insserv` is the package which is *not fully installed or removed*. `dpkg -l | grep rc` will list something different: all packages which have been removed (*r*) but for which the configuration (*c*) has not been purged.

Comment: Did you do something to `/etc/init.d/killprocs`? What is the history here?

Comment: No, not directly. Could it be some of the scripts have removed it? Because it doesn't exist on my disk right now.

Comment: Hmmm... Something has removed it, which is what's causing your immediate problem. Unfortunately, just reinstalling the package won't bring it back, since its a configuration file. You could get it out of the initscripts package using `dpkg-deb -x initscripts….deb /tmp/path` and then copy it back...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/rc1.d/S01killprocs -> ../init.d/killprocs` is missing, obviously, it is in `initscripts`

but `insserv` requires it. [chkrequired](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/insserv/trunk/insserv.c?root=sysvinit&view=markup)

Maybe you can install it manually extracting the `.deb` in some other directory and then copying it to the right place.

```
dpkg -x /var/cache/apt/archives/initscripts_2.88dsf-41_i386.deb /tmp/somedir
```

`2.88dsf-41_i386` is my version, use yours :-)

**edit**

if you get it working manually then re-install it as usual.

Comment: I see your architecture is `armel`, did you used `debootstrap`? I'm not sure if is a bug but seem like a recursive dependency

Comment: No, I have not been using `debootstrap`.

Comment: I had this on an armel embedded system and fixed it with re-placing killprocs from the deb

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue on ubuntu 16.04 by removing all cached .deb files from /var/cache/apt/archives then ran this command:

```
apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I hope this fix problems for someone.

Answer (score 0):

The following command fixed my similar upgrading woes:

```
dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/initscripts_2.88dsf-59.3ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

I was upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 (!) to the next LTS with do-release-upgrade and was stuck with this error:

```
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
  util-linux
```

and dpkg-reconfigure util-linux gave me

```
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: initscripts is broken or not fully installed
```

Even apt-get install --reinstall initscripts produced:

```
E: Internal Error, No file name for initscripts:i386
```

The dpkg (above) worked though, and allowed the upgrade to continue.  Hope this helps someone.