# Why I can not install qt5-default on raspbian buster

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, dependencies, qt

I used katoolin to install some updated qt5 softwares. After I removed the links from the sources.list file everything was okay. I uninstalled the qt5-default then.
Today when I tried to install qt5-default(because I needed to use it) it

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
qt5-default : Depends: qtbase5-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How should I fix this?
When I am trying to install qtbase it is aying it can not be downloaded.
It was working all fine before but now it is corrupted somehow.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Does fixing broken packages work: `apt-get install -f`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixing a broken packet system (apt-get)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97233/fixing-a-broken-packet-system-apt-get)

Comment: I fixed the problem by uninstalling and installing a lot of things. And I also write the answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between systemd and terminal starting program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339638/difference-between-systemd-and-terminal-starting-program)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you add repository and installed from that , your apt was quite badely affected and it couldn't solve the problem. 
Fixing this is a long processs ad this problem can not be eliminated, but can be reduced.
First try to install that package and see the dependency file track that and un install that(because when it is installed you can not continue fixing that)
Now keep repeating it for a while untill you can install your desired package. You have to uninstall everything from the repo you just removed.